# What does the [something] syntax in Swift mean when working with closures?

Tags: swift, closures, self

Normally when capturing reference to a property in a closure I would do something like this -

```swift
foo { [weak self] in
    self?.bar()
}
```

But I have also seen this written as -

```swift
foo { [bar] in
    bar()
}
```

What is meant by `[bar]` and how is this different from capturing a `weak self`?

Comment: It's a capture list. Please read the Swift language guide, cover to cover. It'll answer a whole load of questions like this. https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `[bar]` part is a [capture list](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID57).

It instructs the closures as how values should be captured. When you enter variables in the bracket right before the keyword `in`, the closure is no longer referencing the original variables, instead the closure creates its own copy within the closure block.

Answer (score 1):

That's a capture list, [which can be used to resolve strong reference cycles](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#ID57).
If a closure captures variables by reference (which it does for all reference types), the closure could create a strong reference cycle by being the last object to hold a reference to the captured variable.

A `weak` reference means that it doesn't increase the reference count of the object, so if the last reference to an object is a weak one, its reference count is 0 and hence ARC will deallocate it. This is especially useful for escaping closures, whose lifetime might be longer than the lifetime of the referenced/captured objects and hence the closure could end up holding the last reference to the object and hence wouldn't allow ARC to deallocate it.